# Solr 4.9 Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes

Tags: solr, tomcat6

I've got a huge problem regarding dataimport with mysql connector into solr 4.9.
When i try to launch the request on my db, i always get Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.
The problem is i've nothing into catalina log. Nothing appears even after i've launched the import.
Here is my data-config.xml :

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db" user="user" password="pass"/>
<document name="example">
<entity name="annonce_entry" 
query="SELECT * FROM annonce_entry">
            <field column="annonce_entry_id" name="id" />
            <field column="note_total" name="title" />
</entity>
</document>
```

I settle the connector, create dataimport.properties but still, i've got this message.
Any help ?
Thanks

EDIT :
Here is the ouput response
    {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0
  },
  "initArgs": [
    "defaults",
    [
      "config",
      "data-config.xml"
    ]
  ],
  "command": "status",
  "status": "idle",
  "importResponse": "",
  "statusMessages": {
    "Time Elapsed": "0:0:0.31",
    "Total Requests made to DataSource": "0",
    "Total Rows Fetched": "0",
    "Total Documents Processed": "0",
    "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
    "Full Dump Started": "2015-04-20 09:31:13",
    "": "Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.",
    "Rolledback": "2015-04-20 09:31:13"
  },
  "WARNING": "This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future."
}

Comment: Did you try to set to DEBUG the DIH packages? There must be an error, something....what does the "status" command says?

Comment: Not sure to know how to DEBUG the DIH ?

Comment: Open the admin console, on the left side you will find a menu "logging" with a sub-menu "level"

Comment: Never mind ! i forgot to include mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar so dumb !!

Answer (score 1):

Open Solr admin console. On the left side there's a "Logging" item with a "Level" sub-menu item.

From that page you can enable each single package with a given logging level. You can put DEBUG on DIH packages and for sure you will see what is causing the problem.